# Setting a bokeh attribute inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, bokeh

I see other questions asking about functions inside of iframes, but they don't seem to help me finding this object inside of an iframe.

I have a batch process that generates lots of HTML files.  Each one has a bokeh charts inside.  I need to manually verify a number of these files each time the batch file is run.  I can quickly scan through all of these HTML files and verify them using a simple tool I built.  The tool is just an HTML file that loads one of these files into an iframe, has some custom javascript to speed up the manual verification process, and then loads the next HTML file with a button click.

To speed up the process even further, I'd like to programmatically change the scale of the bokeh chart that is inside the iframe.  Is this possible?

If I load one of the files I'm verifying directly into chrome, I can make the change from the javascript console this way:
Bokeh.index[Object.keys(Bokeh.index)[0]].model.y_range.start = 200;

If I load the HTML file I'm using to speed up the verification process; I can't seem to access the Bokeh object that is loaded inside the iframe.

Is this possible?  Where is the object?

Comment: well sounds like you are trying to either access it before the iframe content is loaded. Is there anerror message in the console when it runs?

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementById('youriframe').contentWindow.Bokeh

This does not work from a file loaded directly into the browser.

It does work from localhost.  The solution is to put the files into a simple web server to serve up the file from http://localhost instead of file://